# How to make ag-Grid table responsive such that headers and rows are transposed?

Tags: html-table, responsive-design, responsive, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

See the "Collapse Rows" animated [example](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/):

[image: animation of responsive tables]

That's similar to what I want to achieve.

I'd like my table to be responsive using the approach of reorganizing itself such that it shows each original row transposed (but also transpose the headers and duplicate them so that they label each row).

ag-Grid seems like a phenomenal library that has countless features, so I was surprised that [the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/) seem not to specify how to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this feature is not available out of the box.

This is actually a feature request which can be found here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/

AG-3142 Allow the grid to change columns for rows (transpose rows), so the grid show each row as one column, and each column as a row

To achieve this, you would have to write a function yourself to transpose the rows into one column.

You can then leverage Grid API methods to update the column and row data accordingly.

I've created a simple [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hyvTHWiqHdP1XFSG) which does this based on a button click:

```
function onBtnClick() {
  let newColumnDefs = [{ field: 'transposed_rows' }];

  let newRowData = [];

  gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node) => {
    let nodeDataValues = Object.values(node.data);
    nodeDataValues.forEach((val) => newRowData.push({ transposed_rows: val }));
  });

  gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(newColumnDefs);
  gridOptions.api.setRowData(newRowData);
}
```